# Prove with the definition of limit

Tags: limits, analysis

I have to prove with the definition of limit this $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+n+2^n} = 0$$

So far I came to this result $$n + 2^n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$$ and I do not how to continue. Any help?

Comment: if $n>\dfrac1\epsilon$ then certainly $n+2^n>\dfrac1\epsilon-1$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the limit is zero we need to show that $\exists n_0$ such that $\forall n>n_0$

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+n+2^n}\right|<\epsilon$$

and since

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+n+2^n}\right|\le \frac{1}{2^n}$$

it suffices assume

$$\frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon \implies 2^n >\frac1\epsilon \implies n>n_0 \ge \frac1{ \log 2}\log \left(\frac 1{\epsilon} \right)$$

Comment: $1/(1+n+2^n)$ is not less than $1/4^n$. I assume you meant less than $1/2^n$.

Comment: @almagest Yes of course! Thanks to have pointed that out! I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically being asked to show that
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists N_\varepsilon \in \mathbb N \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \forall n > N_\varepsilon \quad \left|\frac{1}{1+n+2^n}\right|<\varepsilon .$$
Fix an $\varepsilon > 0$. You need to find a natural number $N_\varepsilon$ such that the inequality on the right is satisfied for all $n > N_\varepsilon$. The first thing to notice is that you can drop the absolute value sign, because all terms in the sequence are positive. Then notice that for all natural $n$
$$n < n + 2^n < 1 + n + 2^n, $$
implying
$$ \frac 1 {1+n+2^n} < \frac 1{n + 2^n} < \frac 1 n, $$
and observe that since $1/n \to 0$ there exists an $N_\varepsilon$ such that $1/n < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N_\varepsilon$. That $N_\varepsilon$ is the natural number you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$2^n\geq n$$ for all $n$, with $$n\geq n_0$$